# Cannot extract .tar.gz file?

Tags: software-installation, gnome-terminal, directory, tar, extract

I installed the `.tar.gz` file for BRL-CAD.
File name is `BRL-CAD_7.26.0.2_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz` at location `/home/user/Downloads`.

I opened Terminal and typed in

```
$ tar -zxvf BRL-CAD_7.26.0.2_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
tar (child): BRL-CAD_7.26.0.2_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What exactly should I type into Terminal so I can extract the .tar.gz file?

Comment: Did you cd to _Downloads_ before running the command?

Comment: You can simply double-click to open it and extract wherever you want and you can also just select "Extract here..."

Comment: @CelticWarrior `You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "bin"`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson How do I command to Downloads before running the command? (i.e. what do I type specifically?)

Comment: @user604803 - No, you don' t but that's NOT part of the question, or is it? The question mentions /home/user/Downloads.

Comment: @user604803 WHY are you using source code (requires compiling) when don' t know the basics, far from it, and there's already a Debian/Ubuntu package (.deb) available? https://sourceforge.net/projects/brlcad/files/BRL-CAD%20for%20Linux/7.26.0/  <- Just download the one for your architecture, double-click it and install. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar -zxvf BRL-CAD_7.26.0.2_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
```

Comment: This extracts the files straight back to `/home/user/Downloads

Comment: Is the extraction destination determined in the files itself? (i.e. Am I unable to control this?)

Comment: @user604803 - Yes, it extracts to the same folder, obviously. No, it's not determined by the file itself.

Comment: @CelticWarrior But for the program to be installed doesn't it need to be extracted to folders in `/`?

Comment: @user604803 It depends on the program and by the look of it this needs to be compiled because it's just source code. The .deb installer will do everything for you.